# Capacitor between two equipotential surfaces

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, capacitance

Is it possible to make a capacitor between two equipotential surfaces?

I asked my teacher and the explanation given was: There is an electric field between the two equipotential surfaces ( Each equipotential surface at different potential ) , thus energy is stored in the volume and if we discharge the energy, it acts like a capacitor.

Is this explanation correct?

Comment: Are you sure about it? What do you mean with "There is an electric field between the two equipotential surfaces"? Electric field is usually given by a _difference_ of potential.

Comment: @fra_pero Each equipotential surface could be at different potentials

Answer (score 4):

Electric charges will only want to move from one point to another point if those points have *different* potentials. That *potential difference* between two points is what we usually call a **voltage**.

An **equipotential surface** is a surface over which there is the same potential at all points. So there is a voltage of zero between all points on this surface. A charge will have no tendency to move away from any point and towards another.

- A **charged metal wire** is an **equipotential line**: All charges spread out so that they all feel as small a repulsion from each other as possible. When they have all stabilised and aren't moving about anymore, then the potential must be the same throughout.
- A **charged metal plate** is an **equipotential surface** of the same reason: All charges spread out as evenly as they can so they feel a smallest possible repulsion from each other. When they have reached this, then all points have the same potential.

A capacitor consists of two such plates. Namely, it consists of one plate at one potential (every point on that plate has the same potential), and another plate with another potential. A capacitor is basically a pair of two equipotential surfaces close to each other without touching.

If you place a charge in between these two plates, then it feels a larger electric force from one plate than from another (or it feels a repulsion from one plate and an attraction towards the other). And so, that charge will want to move towards one of the plates. In other words, those two plates are setting up an electric field between them. This is exactly what a capacitor does - there is a large electric field in the space between the two capacitor plates.

Answer (score 1):

[Steeven's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/552987/179151) is already sufficient. Just to clarify the term equipotential surface. All points on an equipotential surface are already at "equilibrium" with each other. Charges on a spherical conductor for instance would spread out until they are relatively stable and don't repel themselves any longer. Their final positions would make them form an equipotential surface, such that the charges no longer leap or jump from one region of the conductor to another. However, does that imply a equipotential surface cannot attract another charged surface or conductor. No! A charged sphere would still attract another charged metal or conductor. If they are oppositely charged, they repel out and vice versa. Either way, an electric field would always be set up between them. Like charges always attract and dissimilar ones repel. In fact, it is because of this that we can have an equipotential surface namely: similar charges on a conductor keep pushing themselves around until they become stable or will attract each other if they are dissimilarly charged to break the potential(electric discharge/dielectric breakdown). In both cases, the aim is to achieve an equipotential surface.